# IntelliJ Got To Android Code Declarations

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, declaration, goto

I just switched to IntelliJ and had a question in regards to finding declarations. More specifically, finding the declaration of a native Android class. I know the shortcut is Ctrl + B in IntelliJ. So, for instance, if I have a custom class that extends off of Androids Switch widget, and I want to view the Switch class I can highlight (or put my cursor on it) and hit Ctrl + B and it takes me to the class. The class file is pretty bare bones though. I only see the class, constructor definitions and the methods that it holds. The body of the constructors and methods are empty aside from the one line of code

```
throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
```

If I go to the declaration using Eclipse (F3), I can see the code. I can see all of the content which is what I need. Is there a way to do this in intelliJ? All I've found online is the shortcut that takes you there (which I mentioned), nothing else. I'm using IntelliJ 14.0.3

Comment: Anyone use this before?

Comment: anyone use intelliJ?